# Animate Menu on Mouse movement

Tags: jquery, mousemove

I have a function that i would like a menu in from the left side of the page when the mouse is moved to the left side of the screen. And the slide off the left side of the page when the mouse is moved away from the left side.

The issue is since the function is always recording my mouse movements, if the mouse if moved it will register it is past the point and constantly toggle the menu.  I need it to only toggle the menu when it goes past a certain X-coordinate

JS: (EDITED CODE)

```
$("#gridcontainer").mousemove(function(e){

 var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";
 var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";
 $("span:first").text("( e.pageX, e.pageY ) : " + pageCoords);
 $("span:last").text("( e.clientX, e.clientY ) : " + clientCoords);

 var sideMenu = $('.side-menu');

 if (e.pageX < 100 && $('.side-menu').is(":visible")){
    console.log('make visible');
    sideMenu.animate({"left":"-96px"}, 1000);

 }
 else if(!$('.side-menu').is(":visible")){
    sideMenu.animate({"left":"-96px"}, 1000);
    console.log('hide');

 }
```

});

Comment: When you show the menu, don't you want to animate to the right, making your statement `sideMenu.animate({"left":"0px"}, 1000);`? Assuming it started at `left:"-96px"`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to check if the menu is being shown. Try something like

```
 $("#gridcontainer").mousemove(function(e){

    var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";
    var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";
    $("span:first").text("( e.pageX, e.pageY ) : " + pageCoords);
    $("span:last").text("( e.clientX, e.clientY ) : " + clientCoords);

    var sideMenu = $('.side-menu');

    if (e.pageX < 100 && $('.side-menu').is(":visible")){
       console.log('make visible');
       sideMenu.show();
       sideMenu.animate({"left":"-96px"}, 1000);

    }
    else if(!$('.side-menu').is(":visible")){
       sideMenu.animate({"left":"-96px"}, 1000);
       sideMenu.hide();
       console.log('hide');

     }
```

You could even have your show() function do the animation for you. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/show/) for some examples.

Comment: Issue i'm running into is it always thinks the menu is visible, regardless if it moves off screen?

Comment: oops, it looks like you updated your question. You should hide your menu after the animation as it will prevent the menu from being considered in your css placements. This way you can us the visible selector

Answer (score 0):

You could add a toggle boolean variable that triggers when the event is activated and changes when the mouse moves back away from that side. Then just check with an if what's the status of that variable to see if you animate or not.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could put an invisible, absolute div to the left and use the mouseIn and mouseOut functions.

You could also add a class and only run the open code if the class is non-existent. Likewise with the close. Only run when the class exists.

You could also maybe do (e.pageX == 99) and else if (e.pageX == 101). In the else you run code similar to what you have now to make sure it closes/opens incase those numbers didnt register.